# Menu do Bootstrap não funciona

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Sou um iniciante e estou aprendendo Bootstrap, porém após tentar de tudo, não consigo fazer o menu funcionar. 
- Já tentei em outro Pc e outro navegador
- Já baixei as documentações do Bootstrap.css e os .JS
- Já linkei direto pros servidores 
e nada.

Alguém poderia dizer o que está errado?
tenho que instalar alguma coisa?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Praia Hostel</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="O melhor hostel do rio de janeiro">
    <meta name="author" content="Matheus G.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vou comentar aqui pq vc já deletou o código ali. Mas o seu problema está na minha resposta, na verdade o problema não é no código da Navbar e sim nos arquivos indexados que vs usou os da Versão 4, mas com o código HTML da Versão 3 do Bootstrap. Qualquer dúvida comenta lá na resposta que te ajudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua resposta é mais simples do que parece! Vc está tentando usar o "componente" NavBar do **Bootstrap 3**, mas está usando os códigos CSS e JS do **Bootstrap 4**

Repare que dentro do seu `<head>` vc chama o CSS da versão 4 assim como no final do documento vc faz as referencias para os JSs da versão 4 do Bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"...>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js>
```

***Esse é o link correto da documentação Oficial que tem a NavBar da versão 4 caso queira usa-la*** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

O código HTML que vc está usando é o da versão 3. Veja que quando o código é usado no Bootstrap 3 funciona 100%

Eu não mudei nada no seu código apenas chamais os arquivos font da versão correta.Que para esse código é a versão 3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
              <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valeu, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @MatheusGonçalves cuidado com os links que aparecem no google, sempre confira se esta consultando a versão correta que quer usar, boa sorte ai